# Hiding an element of a web page depending on the url

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am loading a form into a page via javascript and I only want to show this form when the url contains a specific expression like: /home.
The form loads for the main page and all sub pages and should only be shown for a sub page containing the above expression, while hidden for all other cases.
I am relatively new to javascript and this problem really strikes me, so any help would be welcome and greatly appreciated.

Best,
Christian

Any help to get started is welcome

This is the original form code in the footer of the page:

```
<div id="zf_div_Bn5V7dbaKmVw_3o0WHIxFJkMwtnNVN84A3_B5az8QIk"></div><script type="text/javascript">(function() {
try{
var f = document.createElement("iframe");
f.src = 'https://forms.heart-life-empowered.com/heartlifeempowered/form/Testcourse1/formperma/Bn5V7dbaKmVw_3o0WHIxFJkMwtnNVN84A3_B5az8QIk?zf_rszfm=1';
f.style.border="none";
f.style.height="2523px";
f.style.width="90%";
f.style.transition="all 0.5s ease";
f.setAttribute("aria-label", 'Test course');

var d = document.getElementById("zf_div_Bn5V7dbaKmVw_3o0WHIxFJkMwtnNVN84A3_B5az8QIk");
d.appendChild(f);
window.addEventListener('message', function (){
var evntData = event.data;
if( evntData && evntData.constructor == String ){
var zf_ifrm_data = evntData.split("|");
if ( zf_ifrm_data.length == 2 ) {
var zf_perma = zf_ifrm_data[0];
var zf_ifrm_ht_nw = ( parseInt(zf_ifrm_data[1], 10) + 15 ) + "px";
var iframe = document.getElementById("zf_div_Bn5V7dbaKmVw_3o0WHIxFJkMwtnNVN84A3_B5az8QIk").getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
if ( (iframe.src).indexOf('formperma') > 0 && (iframe.src).indexOf(zf_perma) > 0 ) {
var prevIframeHeight = iframe.style.height;
if ( prevIframeHeight != zf_ifrm_ht_nw ) {
iframe.style.height = zf_ifrm_ht_nw;
}
}
}
}
}, false);
}catch(e){}
})();</script>
```

With the addition to hide the form:

```
<div id="zf_div_Bn5V7dbaKmVw_3o0WHIxFJkMwtnNVN84A3_B5az8QIk" style="display: none;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">(function() {
try{
var f = document.createElement("iframe");
f.src = 'https://forms.heart-life-empowered.com/heartlifeempowered/form/Testcourse1/formperma/Bn5V7dbaKmVw_3o0WHIxFJkMwtnNVN84A3_B5az8QIk?zf_rszfm=1';
f.style.border="none";
f.style.height="2523px";
f.style.width="100%";
f.style.transition="all 0.5s ease";
f.setAttribute("aria-label", 'Test course');

var d = document.getElementById("zf_div_Bn5V7dbaKmVw_3o0WHIxFJkMwtnNVN84A3_B5az8QIk");
d.appendChild(f);
window.addEventListener('message', function (){
var evntData = event.data;
if( evntData && evntData.constructor == String ){
var zf_ifrm_data = evntData.split("|");
if ( zf_ifrm_data.length == 2 ) {
var zf_perma = zf_ifrm_data[0];
var zf_ifrm_ht_nw = ( parseInt(zf_ifrm_data[1], 10) + 15 ) + "px";
var iframe = document.getElementById("zf_div_Bn5V7dbaKmVw_3o0WHIxFJkMwtnNVN84A3_B5az8QIk").getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
if ( (iframe.src).indexOf('formperma') > 0 && (iframe.src).indexOf(zf_perma) > 0 ) {
var prevIframeHeight = iframe.style.height;
if ( prevIframeHeight != zf_ifrm_ht_nw ) {
iframe.style.height = zf_ifrm_ht_nw;
}
}
}
}
}, false);
}catch(e){}
})();
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Check if the URL contains the specific expression
    var urlContainsExpression = window.location.pathname.includes("/home");

    // Get the form container element
    var formContainer = document.getElementById("zf_div_Bn5V7dbaKmVw_3o0WHIxFJkMwtnNVN84A3_B5az8QIk");

    // Show or hide the form based on the URL condition
    if (urlContainsExpression) {
        formContainer.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        formContainer.style.display = "none";
    }
});</script>
```

This still doesn't work. Now the form does not show up at all, even on a page with the /home in url. Any suggestion would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Could you also include your code that related to that part?

Comment: Sure, it's a ffoter code, adding a form via JS

Comment: Code is in the post now

Comment: Can you please properly indent the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the URL of the page and then display the form based on the specific conditional expression. I'll share a simple example using JavaScript for your trouble.

## HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Your Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Your page content -->

    <div id="formContainer" style="display: none;">
        <!-- Your form goes here -->
    </div>

    <script src="your-script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

## JS

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    // Check if the URL contains the specific expression
    var urlContainsExpression = window.location.pathname.includes("/home");

    // Get the form container element
    var formContainer = document.getElementById("formContainer");

    // Show or hide the form based on the URL condition
    if (urlContainsExpression) {
        formContainer.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        formContainer.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

This code uses the `window.location.pathname` property to get the current page's URL path. It then checks if this path contains the specified expression ("/home") using the includes method. Depending on the result, it sets the display style property of the form container to either "block" (to show) or "none" (to hide).

Answer (score 0):

You can hide element when url does not include '/home' like this

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",() => {
  const currentUrl = window.location.href;
  if (currentUrl.includes("/home")) {
    showForm();
  } else {
    hideForm();
  }
});

const showForm = () => {
  const form = document.getElementById('form-id');
  if (form) {
    form.style.display = 'block';
  }
}

const hideForm = () => {
  const form = document.getElementById('form-id');
  if (form) {
    form.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: Added the code, but the form still showes up, any idea what to do?

Comment: Hi Charles, hides the form now when no "/home" is included, but only showes the form in an url including /home when I reload it. Doesn't show on first load. Do you have an idea about this behavior? Best, Christian

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `<div id="zf_div_Bn5V7dbaKmVw_3o0WHIxFJkMwtnNVN84A3_B5az8QIk"> XXX` into `<div id="a"> XXX`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ColumnCycle Growth</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="a">dsfdsfdsfdsf</div>
    <script>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        // Check if the URL contains the specific expression
        var urlContainsExpression = window.location.pathname.includes("/home");

        // Get the form container element
        var a = document.getElementById("a");

        // Show or hide the form based on the URL condition
        if (urlContainsExpression) {
          a.style.display = "block";
          console.log(true);
        } else {
          a.style.display = "none";
        }
        var f = document.createElement("iframe");
        f.src =
          "https://forms.heart-life-empowered.com/heartlifeempowered/form/Testcourse1/formperma/Bn5V7dbaKmVw_3o0WHIxFJkMwtnNVN84A3_B5az8QIk?zf_rszfm=1";
        f.style.border = "none";
        f.style.height = "2523px";
        f.style.width = "100%";
        f.style.transition = "all 0.5s ease";
        f.setAttribute("aria-label", "Test course");

        var d = document.getElementById("a");
        d.appendChild(f);
        window.addEventListener(
          "message",
          function () {
            var evntData = event.data;
            if (evntData && evntData.constructor == String) {
              var zf_ifrm_data = evntData.split("|");
              if (zf_ifrm_data.length == 2) {
                var zf_perma = zf_ifrm_data[0];
                var zf_ifrm_ht_nw = parseInt(zf_ifrm_data[1], 10) + 15 + "px";
                var iframe = document
                  .getElementById("a")
                  .getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0];
                if (
                  iframe.src.indexOf("formperma") > 0 &&
                  iframe.src.indexOf(zf_perma) > 0
                ) {
                  var prevIframeHeight = iframe.style.height;
                  if (prevIframeHeight != zf_ifrm_ht_nw) {
                    iframe.style.height = zf_ifrm_ht_nw;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          false
        );
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The problem I am facing is that /home is an anchor, like #/home and somehow the anchor in the url loads visibly later, maybe 0.5 seconds after page load, so it is not recognized, because it is not there. If I reload the page, it is ok, the form loads, as the anchor is there already from the previsous load. Question is how do I get the form to load with the first load of the page?